# How to make Joomla k2 item listing with pagination?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I want o make a item listing from joomla k2 module with pagination option but cant make with pagination for items its only for categories. Is any way? or free 
plugins..?

[Example of I want to make](http://www.mtiworldwide.com/index.php/news-and-events).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
Goto- components-> K2-> Categories-> Select your category-> on right side select "category item layout"
->other layout option-> pagination->select auto-> pagination results-> select Show.
For pagination example visit this [link](http://www.program-collection.com/programs)

Comment: One more thing, in order to set the numbers of default items on each page, set the "Leading count" number to desired number